# Asymptotic behavior of $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{m}\frac{1}{\ln(k!)}$

Tags: asymptotics

The task is to find asymptotic behavior of sum:
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{m}\frac{1}{\ln(k!)}$$
when $m\to\infty$.

Any help with solving this one?

Comment: Can you use Stirling's approximation?

Comment: From Stirling's approximation, the denominator goes like $k\log k - k$, so I'd expect the sum to go like $\sum_k1/(k\log k)$, and since the integral of $1/(x\log x)$ is $\log\log x$, that should be asymptotic to $\log\log m$.

Comment: Is this a yandex school problem?

Comment: @Norbert: What's a yandex school problem?

Comment: @Norbert, yes, this's task from homework.

Comment: @joriki, thanks with help. really got confused and didn't see this solution.

Comment: @WickedSpirit now you can answer your question.

Comment: I believe Norbert is suggesting you can post an answer here and then, if it holds up, you can accept it. That way we don't have lots of seemingly-but-not-really unanswered questions lying around.

Comment: I posted below answer to close this question. @joriki, Could you look and check it, please?

Comment: @WickedSpirit: It's not quite rigorous, since you don't justify dropping the $O(n)$ term or replacing the sum by an integral, but I don't know what level of rigour you were aiming for -- it's good enough to convince me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Stirling's approximation:
$$\ln(n!)\sim n\ln(n)+O(n)$$

Next we approximate sum with integral:
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{m}\frac{1}{k\ln(k)}\sim\int_{2}^{m}\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)}=\ln\ln(m)-\ln\ln(2)$$

Found asymptotic behavior — $\ln \ln(n)$.

Comment: Looks good, although it's probably worth justifying the approximation of the sum with an integral - even if only by saying 'by Euler-MacLaurin'...